# Azure Permission Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel, azure

I deployed my laravel app on Azure
i've changed the Virtual applications and directories to point to /public

i configured the database connection & migrated etc...

when i browse to `mywebsite.azuresites.net/`

it throws this error

> ErrorException in compiled.php line 7310:
>   file_put_contents(/79aa254227239a520e87412b44eed555ed812978.php):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied

I could not manage to make this work! any help ?

Comment: I have tryed using laravel with azure, but I had a lots of issues, so I better created a virtual ubuntu server on azure, and it works like charm. I'd recomend you the same.

Comment: if this issue gets fixed! this would be a 3 mins deploy, so the only probleme is the first time as usual (but ill give it a shot with that)

Comment: You'll have a lots of other issues, because Laravel is best for linux/unix enviorement.

Comment: Does your application work fine if you remove the virtual applications and directories settings?

Comment: found the solution and the app works , now its very easy :D thank you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix was so easy but tricky

after deploying with github there is no `views` folder in `storage/framework`

the fix was just to create the folder `views` there